# Pipe command to suppress output on success

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm running a command that always prints some output. I want to see the output only if the command fails.

Something like this:

`% (echo OK;    true)  | FILTER
% (echo ERROR; false) | FILTER
ERROR`

Can `FILTER` be implemented using standard shell tools?
The structure isn't necessarily a pipe. Something like `FILTER "my_command"` is OK.

P.S. The actual program is a unit test, implemented using the Google Test suite. It's always quite verbose, and in case of success the output isn't interesting.

Comment: Will there be a sub-shell present always? `()` or just an example shown here?

Comment: `a=$(echo OK;    true) || echo "$a"`; `a=$(echo ERROR;    false) || echo "$a"`;

Comment: @Inian, no - the subshell is just an attempt write a clear example.

Comment: @anishsane, Works well unless there are newlines in the output. Inian's answer deals with them too.

Comment: @ugoren, By any chance, did you miss quotes in `echo "$a"`? Because with quotes, it should work just fine even for multiline output... e.g. `a=$(echo hi; echo; echo hello; false) || echo "$a"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You *DONT* need a sub-shell in your case, as you can see below, the exit code of a command set ( a list of commands separated by ';'), is the exit code of last command in the set. So only `true` or `false` at the end matters in your examples. None of the commands before matter.

The best way to do this would be to use a command-substitution(`$()`), capture the output to a variable and use the shell built-in `||` operator, that runs the subsequent command only if the return code of the previous command is a failure.

```
var=$(echo ERROR); false || printf "%s\n" "$var"
ERROR

var=$(echo ERROR); true || printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

The inverse of the above clause would be

```
var=$(echo ERROR); true && printf "%s\n" "$var"
ERROR

var=$(echo ERROR); false && printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

See what the `man` page has to say about for `COMMAND LISTS`

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one of more pipelines separated by the `&&` and `||` control operators, respectively.  `AND` and `OR` lists are executed with left associativity.  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> *command2* is executed if, and only if, *command1* returns an exit status of zero. An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> *command2* is executed if and only if *command1* returns a non-zero exit status.  The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last command executed in the list.

Comment: Saving an unknown amount of data in a shell variable seems awkward to me, but it works, and the `printf` deals well with newlines (unline `echo`).

Comment: The use of `(echo OK; true)` was just an example - in practice it's one executable - so I can't capture only the first part. But fixing it is easy `var=$(echo OK; true) && printf "%s\n" "$var"` works the same

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect stdout to /dev/null with this:

```
command 1>/dev/null
```

This way, only error messages appear.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I want to suppress all output on success, show all output on error.